# How can I compare what data value changed over two periods?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

For my Fantasy Football League I'd like to quickly be able to compare the data of two data sets to see who moved up/down the table over a week period (two different sets of data).

Here's an example of what I want to do (calculate the change from Week 1 to Week 2).

Team 4 for example has moved up four places.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Super User. We are not a script writing service. We expect users to tell us what they have tried so far (including any scripts they are using) and where they're stuck so that we can help with specific problems. Questions that only ask for scripts are too broad and are likely to be [put on hold or closed](http://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions). Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 4):

You can use INDEX & MATCH functions to return the position from Week2 table.
Say if Week1 table is in columns A, B, C & D and Week2 in H, I ,J then
`=INDEX($H$2:$H$6,MATCH(B2,$I$2:$I$6,0),1)`
shall return the Week2 position.

See here a sample screenshot.[image]

Comment: pat2015: Looks like you were quicker to answer than I =) (+1 from me)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the match function to return the row in which the corresponding lookup value is located, then using that row, use the index function to return the position.  Once you know the position, it is as simple as subtracting it from the prior value:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Use the [MATCH function](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/MATCH-function-e8dffd45-c762-47d6-bf89-533f4a37673a) to determine last week's position assuming *no duplicate* team names and last week's table is in *ascending* order of team position.

1. Add a column where you want last weeks position to be displayed.
2. Use MATCH function to lookup the team of interest, against last week's table of teams and ask for exact match only.

   `=MATCH(current team, last weeks team name table, 0 = exact match only)`

If the team you're looking up is 3rd from the top of the table last week, the function will display "3".  I'm sure you can do the final subtraction to work out the *change*.

The advantage over other answer is you don't need to use `INDEX`, unless last week's table is in a different order (why?), in which case the other answer has you covered.